# Update a Django Filefield with Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to update an existing objects' FileField with Ajax. A wav blob is created in the browser, and I'm trying to pass it by appending it to a FormData instance:

```
var data = new FormData();
            data.append('sound', blob);


$.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'posts:update_audio' instance.pk %}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,   
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
              alert('success');
                }
            });
            return false;
            }
```

I'm passing the pk through the url to the view, because (correct me if I'm wrong) but I think thats the way to specify the path to the correct objectt to be updated. Here is the view:

```
def update_audio(request,pk):
    form = UpdateAudio(request.POST or None, request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':


        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)      
            instance.save()


    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Which I just treated like any other view which submits a form. I'm a bit confused about how this is supposed to update the specific object, which leads me to my question: Should I be using a special view for this, like UpdateView? If so, how can I implement it? If not, anyone know where I'm going wrong? I'm currently just getting an internal server error 500 when I try and submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your form to this

```
instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=pk)
form = MyUpdateAudioForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

and ajax url to

```
url: "{% url 'posts:update_audio' pk=instance.pk %}",
```

Comment: You have no idea how much you've just helped me out. Much gratitude exprator!